# Execute local script on remote Linux host

Tags: bash, root, host

I have a local script that will not run without root privs on the remote host. I have edited and allowed the sudoers file to run the script from the home dir (/home/username/script). The script creates a txt file with the results but I redirect the output to terminal and pipe the output to a text file on the local machine.

I cannot "ssh user@hostname sudo -Sv < script.sh > results.txt" because this will not run the script from the remote host, specifically the home dir.

Does anyone know of a way (one line) to copy the script to the remote host & execute it as root while retrieving the output?

Thank you for any assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the script with `scp`, then run it.

```
scp script.sh user@hostname:
ssh user@hostname sudo ./script.sh > results.txt
```

To do it in one line:

```
ssh user@hostname 'cat > script.sh; chmod 755 script.sh; sudo ./script.sh' < script.sh > results.txt
```

However, this won't work if you need to enter a password into `sudo`. All of `ssh`'s stdin will be put in the script. There might be a way to do this using `Expect`, but I don't have much expertise there.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! The ssh keys aren't stored so I will need to enter a 14 char pswd both when scp'ing and ssh'ing. Is there a way to one-line it?

Comment: I won't need to enter a password for sudo (running the script). This seems like it will work great! Also,Thanks a lot for your time and help!!

Comment: It isn't a correct response to the question, it was about running a command remotely, not pushing to remote machine!

Comment: The last line of the question says _copy the script to the remote host & execute it_.

Answer (score 12):

if you have sudo, AND allowed to sudo to root, then this works with a bit less syntax:

`ssh -T user@hostname 'sudo su -' < script.sh`