# How to run commands to change file text file in remote host using bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh

Hello I'm running a bash script to change a keyword on a text file but it is located @ my remote host (10.101.5.91), I tried with this sample code, but it does not change anything on that file, and also no errors to be shown.

---

```
changeConfig(){
    shopt -s globstar
    for file in $1
    do
            sed -i.bak 's/$2/$3/g' $file
    done
}

remoteFunction(){
    ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 "`declare -f changeConfig`; changeConfig /var/www/file.txt
}

remoteFunction
```

---

Can anyone help me? Thankx.... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001544/execute-local-script-on-remote-linux-host

Answer (score 0):

Following will change that keyword

```
#!/bin/bash
file='/path/on/remotehost/filename'      #PATH on remote host
ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 "sed -i.bak "s/$2/$3/g" $file"    #Would work without password if ssh keys exchanges else will ask $ wait for password
```

Don't know what you are doing with `$1` though.